# mixed() vs lmer() output for fixed effect factor labels: numeric vs character

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I've noticed that when specifying a model using the `lmer` function in the `lme4` package which contains factor-type predictors, the suffix indicating the level of the predictor is a character string of that factor level, as is the case for treatment here:

```
library(afex)

data(obk.long)

m1 <- lmer(value ~ treatment + (1|id), obk.long)
summary(m1)

Fixed effects:
        Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    4.200      0.654    6.43
treatmentA     2.050      0.980    2.09
treatmentB     1.800      0.856    2.10
```

However, when using the `mixed` function in the `afex` package, the suffix is numeric:

```
m2 <- mixed(value ~ treatment + (1|id), obk.long)
summary(m2$full.model) # this should be the same as the lmer output... it's er, not

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    5.483      0.375   14.62
treatment1    -1.283      0.532   -2.41
treatment2     0.767      0.565    1.36
```

Does anyone know what causes the difference in the predictor label level suffix and/or the differences in the fixed effects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`afex` sets the contrast coding for categorical predictors as a sum contrast by default (which is mentioned in a message when you use `mixed`), while the model specified in the `lmer` call uses the contrast setting from R's global options.

```
options('contrasts')
##$contrasts
##        unordered           ordered 
##"contr.treatment"      "contr.poly" 

obk2 <- obk.long
contrasts(obk2$treatment) <- "contr.sum"

# Or alternatively, set the global option with something like:
# options(contrasts=c('contr.sum', 'contr.poly'))

m_contr <- lmer(value ~ treatment + (1|id), obk2)

summary(m_contr)$coefficients # fixed effects only for brevity
##              Estimate Std. Error   t value
##(Intercept)  5.4833333  0.3751349 14.616966
##treatment1  -1.2833333  0.5321163 -2.411753
##treatment2   0.7666667  0.5645823  1.357936

all.equal(summary(m2)$coefficients, summary(m_contr)$coefficients)
##[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers one of my two questions!

Comment: Actually, you answered **both** questions, accepted: a more detailed answer by Henrik can be seen [here](https://github.com/singmann/afex/issues/4)

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting in the future, as it leads to duplication of effort. Based on your subsequent post there, I think a more general guide to contrast codes might be useful, like http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm